# I want to select specific row when i click button using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select specific row when i click the delete button or edit button in my table because every row in my table have 2 buttons one for delete and other for edit but it delete the row has the last id not the row i want it .
I want when i click the button in the same row the row deleted .
look for the below image please to understand what i mean

[image: Picture for the table]

I'm using this code to create the table

```
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {               
                echo '
                <tr class="w3-hover-orange">
                     <td>
                         <a class="links" href="topic.php?id=' . $row['topic_id'] . '">' . $row['topic_subject'] . '</a>
                     </td>                   
                     <td>
                        ' . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['topic_date'])) . ' 
                     </td>                                
                     <td> 
                     </td>                  
                     <td>    
                    <a href="edit_topic.php" name="topicEdit"  id = "topicEdit" class = "w3-button tableButtons" >Edit</a>
                     <button href="#" name="topicDelete" type="button" id="topicDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class ="w3-button tableButtons">Delete</button>

                     </td>
                     </tr>';
                  $_SESSION['topic_id_number'] = $row['topic_id'];
                 $_SESSION['topciSubject'] = $row['topic_subject'];
 }

            echo'</table></form></div>';
```

And below the code for the delete topic

```
 if(isset($_POST['topicDelete'])){
$delete = $_SESSION['topic_id_number'];
$query = "DELETE FROM topics WHERE topic_id =".$delete;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
header ("location: awareness-projects.php");

}
```

Comment: You're using the same `id=topicEdit` and `id=topicDelete` in each row. IDs are supposed to be unique. you shouldn't repeat them like that.

Comment: any idea to rename them ?

Comment: Are you sure you need the IDs in the first place? Maybe you should use classes instead.

Comment: You could append the topic ID, e.g. `id="topicEdit-{$row['topic_id']}"`

Comment: I Found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655298/deleting-row-in-a-table-with-delete-button-in-php
The best way it's to add <form> to each row .

Answer (score 0):

I think `$row['topic_id']` id the id against which delete is to be performed.

Make following changes:

```
<button href="#" name="topicDelete" type="button" id="topicDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class ="w3-button tableButtons">Delete</button>
```

change it to an `anchor` and in its `href` pass this `$row['topic_id']` and get its value on the deletion page like:

```
<a href="xyz.php?id='".$row['topic_id'] ."'"
```

Comment: could you explain more please

Answer (score 0):

As the table entries are being generated dynamically through the loop it will always take the last id when the loop is finished because the session name you use is the same for every while loop entry. so it will be overwrite every time and the last id will be in the session variable.
There are several options you can try

1. Name the session variable for every loop in such a way that it is different for every loop
2. second is storing the id of current record in data attribute of the anchor tag, so you have to change the button tag to  anchor tag, then follow the following:

`<a href="#" name="topicDelete" type="button" id="topicDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class ="w3-button tableButtons" data-cid="$row['topic_id']">Delete</a>`

then when you click the link get the value of the current link using the following code of jquery and store it into the hidden field of the modal

```
$(".tableButtons").click(function(){
    var  id=$(this).data("cid");
    alert(id);//check the id if you are getting current id or not
    $("#temp").attr("value",id);//this is the hidden field in modal which id is temp and name it to whatever name you use to get the value of it in your delete code  
});
```

whenever you will submit the form this hidden field's value will be set with the value of the id and will be submitted if  you are using the form action method.
then you can  retrieve the value of it as a normal textbox as you have already done many times I hope so.
All The Best.
I am personally using this code for my work and it works completely fine ;)

Comment: it's delete the last id

Comment: i edit the data-cid to data-cid=" ' . $row['topic_id'] . ' " because there's problem when i write like you

Answer (score -1):

Send topic_id with query-string as follows

```
<a href="xyz.php?id='".$row['topic_id']."'" name="topicDelete" type="button" id="topicDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class ="w3-button tableButtons">Delete</a>
```

Delete code -

```
if(isset($_POST['topicDelete'])){
$delete = $_GET['id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM topics WHERE topic_id =".$delete;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
header ("location: awareness-projects.php");
}
```

Comment: do `button` have `href` attribute?

Comment: no i don't have href attribute because the delete code in the same page